# Does azure provide a REST API for databases? Or do I have to write my own?

Tags: azure

We need to write a very quick web application hosted on azure.  Backed by sql database.  I kind of hoping we don't need to start creating a full webapi project with visual studio - routing, EF etc.  It would be great if azure could provide a rest api for my database.

I think dreamfactory might be doing this.  But I tried to use their free trial but it didn't allow sql server unless you sign up.

I would have thought this would be a standard requirement for small apps.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by "rest API for my database" is the possibility to use JSON documents against it, then you should definitely look at [documentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/)

It provides:

- JSON based document access and indexing,
- Low latency & scaling,
- Support for [mongoDB driver](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-protocol-mongodb/)

To complement this answer, DocumentDB is also capable to be accessed using client-side JS as shown [here](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js/) but only with specific Windows 8/10 sdks

So bottom line is: DocumentDB can't be directly accessed.

Comment: Are you saying that if I used documentDB, I would not need a server side API to connect to the database?  I could call into a documentDB end-point directly from javascript code on the client side?

Comment: So I'd need to code up all the database access, routing etc.  Back to square one.  I agree that firebase would be great, but client is insisting on azure.  Full app needs building in a few days.

Comment: @bsoulier ... While DocumentDB does have a client side JS but it is not something that you can use in a web application as DocumentDB doesn't have CORS support just yet. From what I understand, this JS based client side library is for building Windows 8/10 apps.

Comment: Also, I don't think DocumentDB is a replacement for SQL Database. Both of them serve unique purposes and just because DocumentDB offers REST API while SQL Database not doesn't mean that once can use DocumentDB.

Answer (score 0):

If DocumentDB serves your purpose and CORS is the only issue then you can use Azure API Management as a gateway between ui/js and back-end DocDB. CORS can be enabled at APIM with a policy expression.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/7689d277-8abe-472a-a78c-e6d4bd43455d#CORS